# Android UI Tests Only Show Skipped Tests in Gradle Output

Tags: user-interface, testing, android-testing, gradle-android-test-plugi, android-test-orchestrator

When I run just the UI tests on a gradle managed device it only shows Skipped tests in the out put.  I have set up the logging level but it is ignore it for UI tests.  Am I missing something?

```
testOptions {
    execution = "ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR"
    animationsDisabled = true
    unitTests {
        isIncludeAndroidResources = true
        all {
            it.maxHeapSize = "2048m"
            // added this to try and it doesn't do anything for the UI tests only unit tests.
            it.testLogging {
                events(TestLogEvent.FAILED, TestLogEvent.PASSED, TestLogEvent.SKIPPED, TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT, TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR)
                showStandardStreams = true
                showStackTraces = true
            }
        }
    }
```

gradle command and out put of 6 tests one skipped

```
./gradlew phonesGroupDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.android.regressions.OnboardingRegressions
> Task :app:pixel2api31DebugAndroidTest
Starting 6 tests on pixel2api31

com.example.android.regressions.OnboardingRegressions > Onboarding_Privacy[pixel2api31] SKIPPED 

> Task :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestTestResultProtos
Test execution completed. See the report at: ....
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 54s
```

Run the gradle command for the Unit tests it shows all 3 types SKIPPED, FAILED and PASSED.

Is there another setting in androidTests that I am missing in gradle?